# ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.contrib.memusage.MemoryUsage': No module named uu

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been using scrapy on Mac for over 6 months now when today, out of nowhere I start getting this issue.

I ran it like I normally do using "scrapy crawl ". I also tried checking my twisted installation, which is working fine.

Here is the complete stacktrace of the issue:

```
2015-11-16 17:07:00+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.6 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-11-16 17:07:00+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-11-16 17:07:00+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Crawler.spiders', 'Crawler.availability_spiders'], 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in 
sys.exit(execute())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
func(a, *kw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 60, in run
self.crawler_process.start()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 92, in start
if self.start_crawling():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 124, in start_crawling
return self._start_crawler() is not None
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 139, in _start_crawler
crawler.configure()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 46, in configure
self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 29, in from_settings
mwcls = load_object(clspath)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 42, in load_object
raise ImportError("Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e))
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.contrib.memusage.MemoryUsage': No module named uu
```

If someone has any ideas on why this is happening, please help.

EDIT : Upon upgrading scrapy, that issue seems to have gone away, however, I am now getting another issue :

```
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Crawler.spiders', 'Crawler.availability_spiders'], 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name pyopenssl'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

2015-11-16 19:57:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 83, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.scheduler_cls = load_object(self.settings['SCHEDULER'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from queuelib import PriorityQueue
  File "/Users/pravesh/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/queuelib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from queuelib.queue import FifoDiskQueue, LifoDiskQueue
  File "/Users/pravesh/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
exceptions.ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
2015-11-16 19:57:21 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Comment: update your scrapy version (0.24.6 is way too old), `uu` module maybe comes with `uuid`, so `pip install uuid`

Comment: I've used pip install --upgrade scrapy and that successfully installed scrapy 1.0.3. But when I run scrapy, it still shows scrapy this old version. How can I force it to use new version?

Comment: @eLRuLL : Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I reinstalled scrapy to get latest version. Now I am on Scrapy 1.0.3. Now I get another error saying 2015-11-16 19:31:21 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred: .... .... exceptions.ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 I cannot figure out the use of sqlite here? Could you please help on that as well.

I've updated the complete logs in the question.

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: @eLRuLL : It is Python 2.7.10

Comment: that's weird, sqlite should come with that python version. I recommend to isolate a python env, use virtualenv and install everything inside it, maybe some python modules are conflicting in your system.

Comment: Alright. I'll try that. The weird thing is that I have another scrapy project which is working completely fine. I don't know what is wrong with this one.

Comment: I don't know what I messed up in my project for it to stop working, but I took another pull from github and that one was working fine. So I just deleted the current one and started using the new one taken from git.

Thanks for all you help @eLRuLL.